# Valgrind jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) using getline and one char *

Tags: c, unix, valgrind, realloc

I am trying to use `getline` and a char pointer to store all results of `getline` to that one pointer:

```c
    char *final = NULL;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    ssize_t result;
    int current_size = 0;
    while ((result = getline(&line, &n, in)) != -1){
        current_size += result;
        final = realloc(final, current_size ); //valgrind error
        if (final== NULL)
            return NULL;
        strcat(final,line);
    }
```

But I always get the error:

```
==695== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==695==    at 0x483B6D0: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==695==    by 0x483E017: realloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
... method trace
```

I know, that realloc just allocates, not initalises values, but if I try to memset in the next line, valgrind tells me:

```
==695== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==695==    at 0x48428EC: memset (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
... method trace
```

I read a lot of SO contributions, but could not manage to fix that problem with the solutions shown in those. I am sure that that's not the worst memory-leak, but it's still one, so I am trying to fix it.
Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

Comment: I wonder if you somehow managed to simplify the problem itself out of the code as well. [mre] would be nice.

Comment: BTW a memory leak is when you fail to free allocated memory. Valgrind complaining about uninitialized memory is strictly speaking not one. A potential memory error yes, leak no.

Comment: Where is the room for `'\0'` in `final = realloc(final, current_size );`? What happens when `strcat(final,line);` tries to add one? (UB?)

Comment: As the code now stands, in the first iteration you do malloc + strcat without initializing the alloced memory first, this is clearly wrong.

Comment: @dratenik: You're absolutely right this valgrind error doesn't indicate a memory leak. There is a leak in this code though: if `realloc` fails (returns `NULL`), then `final` won't have been freed, but there will be no remaining pointer to it so it will be impossible to free.

Comment: @dratenik - that's not right. `malloc()` and then `strcat()` to the allocated block is fine (provided there is enough space)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin malloc does not zero memory, strcat looks for the first zero byte in dest and appends src there. Are you sure that is fine? I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Probably the loop would work better if instead of NULL you started with one byte and set it to zero. That would also resolve the problem of allocating the extra byte for the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers/discussions, I will try them and look what I come up with!

Comment: @dratenik - you are correct there -- the problem is where `current_size` is incremented. On the first iteration, you need to set `*final = 0;` to make `final` an empty-string before calling `strcat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but your use of `current_size += result;` before the call to `realloc()` prevents a simple check of `current_size == 0` to check for the first iteration which you would then want to initialize `final` as an *empty-string*.

You can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char *final = NULL, *line = NULL;
    size_t n = 0, current_size = 0;
    ssize_t result;
    
    while ((result = getline(&line, &n, stdin)) != -1) {
        if (result > 0)
            line[--result] = 0;                                 /* trim \n */
        
        final = realloc (final, current_size + result + 1);     /* add room for \0 */
        if (final== NULL)                                       /* validate allocation */
            return 1;
        
        if (!current_size)                                      /* if 1st word */
            *final = 0;                                         /* make final empty-str */
        
        current_size += result;                                 /* now update value */
        strcat (final, line);                                   /* concatenate */
    }
    
    printf ("%zu - %s\n", current_size, final);
    
    free (final);
    free (line);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getlineplusone << 'eof'
1234
56
789
eof
9 - 123456789
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/getlineplusone << 'eof'
1234
56
789
eof
==8438== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8438== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8438== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8438== Command: ./bin/getlineplusone
==8438==
9 - 123456789
==8438==
==8438== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8438==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8438==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 5,262 bytes allocated
==8438==
==8438== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8438==
==8438== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8438== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```